# Text encoding translation in clojure

Tags: encoding, clojure

I'd like to write a clojure function that takes a string in one encoding and converts it to another. The iconv library does this.

For example, let's look at the character "è". In ISO-8859-1 (http://www.ascii-code.com/), that's `e8` as hex. In UTF-8 (http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=%C3%A8&mode=char), it's `c3 a8`.

So let's say we have iso.txt, which contains our letter and EOL:

```
$ hexdump iso.txt                               
0000000 e8 0a                  
0000002
```

Now we can convert it to UTF-8 like this:

```
$ iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 iso.txt | hexdump
0000000 c3 a8 0a                                       
0000003
```

How should I write something equivalent in clojure? I'm happy to use any external libraries, but I don't know where I'd go to find them. Looking around I couldn't figure out how to use libiconv itself on the JVM, but there's probably an alternative?

**Edit**

After reading Alex's link in the comment, this is so simple and so cool:

```
user> (new String (byte-array 2 (map unchecked-byte [0xc3 0xa8])) "UTF-8")
"è"

user> (new String (byte-array 1 [(unchecked-byte 0xe8)]) "ISO-8859-1")
"è"
```

Comment: A point of clarification: strings in Java (and therefore in Clojure) are defined as a sequence of Unicode characters, and therefore always have the same representation. It's only when translating between strings/characters and underlying bytes that encoding comes into play.

Comment: @alex I see, but how would I do it operating on the byte level then? Is there a way to convert the hex value `e8` to the string which is the unicode character 'è'?

Comment: I recommend reading this: http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want a simple whole-file conversion to UTF-8, `slurp` allows for specifying the file encoding with the `:encoding` option and `spit` will output UTF-8 by default. This method will read the entire file into memory, so large files might require a different approach.

```
$ printf "\xe8\n" > iso.txt
$ hexdump iso.txt
0000000 e8 0a                                          
0000002

(spit "/Users/path/iso2.txt"
      (slurp "/Users/path/iso.txt" :encoding "ISO-8859-1"))

$ hexdump iso2.txt
0000000 c3 a8 0a                                       
0000003
```

**Note:** `slurp` will assume UTF-8 if you do not specify an encoding.

Comment: Thanks! Accepting this since it answered a large chunk of my confusion

Comment: How can you translate the encoding of a string?

Comment: Thanks a lot.

In my case (I know that my UTF16 contains Latin1 only):

`(defn convert_utf16_to_latin1 [file-in file-out]
    (spit file-out
        (slurp file-in :encoding "UTF-16") 
        :encoding "ISO-8859-1"))`